# Storing base64 data in XML?

Tags: xml, language-agnostic, base64, cdata

How I can store base64 strings in XML?

Do you use CDATA to store base64 strings in XML? Would it help as it allows use of < > within the strings?

Is base64 configurable where you tell it not to use certain chars if they conflict with XML?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can just store it as a text or attribute value; no escaping or `CDATA` sections needed. The standard base 64 characters `+` and `/` (other than `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`) do not interfere with XML parsing at all.

Answer (score 23):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) only uses alphanumeric characters and '+' (plus), '/' (slash) and '=' (equals). No need to encode anything for XML.

Comment: To me this looks like the more correct answer as most base 64 implementations use +, / and =

Answer (score 13):

There are no characters whatsoever in the Base64 charset that will conflict with XML strings.