# Why are null char disallowed even in CDATA sections?

Tags: xml, null, cdata

XML, Why are null char disallowed even in CDATA sections?

It seems to terminate the file right there.

Any solution? Base64?

Comment: Good question, can't think of anything except base64 (or some delimiter).

Comment: I'm very curious, why would you want to have nulls inside XML? It amazes me seeing binary streams inside XML.

Comment: @João: because he wants to transfer binary data in old versions of Flash without the overhead of base64 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502857/use-cdata-to-store-raw-binary-streams

Comment: Because you might want to send some arbitrary binary data via a web service for example. I have some error reporting code that calls a web service to report the error and also (optionally) sends the binary file that the app was working on at the time.
Makes debugging my users crashes so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find your answer in this previous question:

[Why are "control" characters illegal in XML 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404107/why-are-control-characters-illegal-in-xml)

Answer (score 4):

Because it's no [valid XML character](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets), ie it should produce a parse error. This is likely because of historical reasons (null terminated strings) and because of XML's plain-text nature: Anything on which a Unicode-capable editor might choke is discouraged...

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't 'terminate the file', but it should generate a well-formedness error. It's disallowed because so much of the world is still using null-terminated string processing, so allowing a \0 is likely to cause trouble at some unspecified point down the processing chain.

This can possibly even be a security vulnerability; there have been many exploits in the past that have relied on the interfacing of systems which allow \0 and those which take it as a terminator. The safest thing to do, therefore, is simply to disallow it.

Other control characters can be escaped as &#...; character references elsewhere in XML 1.1, but not in CDATA sections. In XML 1.0 there is no way to get control characters in at all. It is, after all, supposed to be a text-based, human-readable format.

> Base64?

Yes. But if you are processing mostly big chunks of binary, encapsulating it in XML is probably not a reasonable choice.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're required to store big chunks of binary data in an XML document, base 64 encoding is the way to do it.