# Parsing XML CDATA with Xmllite

Tags: xml, xmllite

The issue: 
When readin CDATA elements, carriage return (0xD) are omitted from the output.

Is there a proper way to tell Xmllite to keep CR, 
or should I always need a Replace(LF,CRLF) call?

Thanks I.A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour (replacing 'carriage return, line feed' with 'line feed') is required by any conforming XML parser (section 2.11 of the xml 1.0 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends). If you want both control characters in your output you will need to add the carriage return to the string after parsing.