# Attaching files to WCF REST service responses

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a resource that looks something like this:

```
/users/{id}/summary?format={format}
```

When `format` is "xml" or "json" I respond with a user summary object that gets automagically encoded by WCF - fine so far.  But when `format` equals "pdf", I want my response to consist of a trivial HTTP response body and a PDF file attachment.

How is this done?  Hacking on `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse` doesn't seem to work, and wouldn't be the right thing even if it did.  Including the bits of the file in a CDATA section or something in the response [isn't safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502857/use-cdata-to-store-raw-binary-streams).  Should I create a subclass of `Message`, then provide a custom `IDispatchMessageFormatter` that responds with it?  I went a short distance down that path but ultimately found the documentation opaque.

What's the right thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that what I need is WCF "raw" mode, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosfigueira/wcf-raw-programming-model-web).  Broadly speaking, I want to do this:

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/users/{id}/summary?format={format}"]
public Stream GetUserSummary(string id, string format)
{
    if(format == "pdf")
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        return new MemoryStream(CreatePdfSummaryFileForUser(id));
    }
    else
    {
        // XML or JSON serialization.  I can't figure out a way to not do this explicitly, but my use case involved custom formatters anyway so I don't care.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, just curious if you could share how you setup the client binding for this to work...

Comment: There isn't one, it's REST, you hit a URL and get back an HTTP response.  Hvae I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 3):

In theory you could do it with a multi-part content MIME type (see http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2387.html).  However, it would be much easier to return a URL in the XML/JSON response and the client can do a GET on that link to return the file.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  Is returning a URL considered best practice? ( instead of returning an entire file)