# Converting binary data to UTF-8 for embedding

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I'd like to encode binary data more efficiently than Base64 for transferring data to browsers. It doesn't need to be human-readable, it should just survive being transferred as UTF-8.

Since not all byte sequences are valid UTF-8, the data needs to be converted somehow.

It would need to be a solution that works in the browser.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not use compression like [GZIP](https://github.com/beatgammit/gzip-js) or [LSW](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html)?

Comment: Please check [Encoding binary data within XML: Are there better alternatives than base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301940/encoding-binary-data-within-xml-are-there-better-alternatives-than-base64) and [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Hmm you are right - I tried converting a compressed image to base64, and then gzipping it, and it yielded only a few % increase.
Between that and the excellent links that ÁlvaroGonzález found, I'll close this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)

Comment: @w00t You shouldn't need to use base64 encoding as long as you're compressing it. I believe that might earn you quite a few % off the final payload.

Comment: The problem is transferring the data over a channel JS understands…