# Additional information: Unable to translate bytes [FF] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode

Tags: vb.net, serialization

I have made a small application to serialize and deserialize an image in xml. What I'm attempting to do is serialize then deserialize it as a bitmap type and return it. I then want to put this image into a listbox so I created a pictureBox pro-grammatically however when I try and cast the memory stream as a Bitmap I get the following error `Additional information: Unable to translate bytes [FF] at index 0 from specified code page to Unicode` which is a `DescoderFallbackException`. I'm unsure what `GetType` I should be giving the XMLSerializedr class but I assume it's Bitmap.

My code is as follows

Code for calling Serializer and Deserializer method and getting returned image to put in picturebox

```
 Dim mem As MemoryStream

            Serialize()
            Dim pic As Bitmap = Deserialize(mem)
            ListBoxTemplates.Items.Clear()
            Dim selectedCatID = AppSettings.PowerPoint.TemplateCategories.SingleOrDefault(Function(t) t.Name = ComboBoxNewLevel1.Text).ID
            Dim selectedCat2ID = AppSettings.PowerPoint.TemplateCategories.SingleOrDefault(Function(t) t.Name = ComboBoxNewLevel2.Text).ID


            Dim level3Cat = From Temp In AppSettings.PowerPoint.PSLTemplates
                            Join cat In AppSettings.PowerPoint.TemplateCategories On Temp.CategoryLevel1ID Equals cat.ID
                            Where Temp.CategoryLevel1ID = selectedCatID And selectedCat2ID = Temp.CategoryLevel2ID
                            Select Temp.Name

            For Each t In level3Cat

                Dim pb As PictureBox = New PictureBox()

                pb.Location = Location()

                pb.Name = ""
                pb.BackgroundImage = pic


                ListBoxTemplates.Items.Add(pb)
            Next
```

Serialize Method

```
Public Sub Serialize()

    Dim corolla As New Bitmap("C:\xmltext.png", True)


    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()

    corolla.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    Dim sw As New StringWriter()

    Dim xw As New XmlTextWriter(sw)

    xw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

    Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(ms.GetBuffer().[GetType]())

    ser.Serialize(xw, ms.GetBuffer())

    Debug.WriteLine("Serialized Content::")

    Dim sSerializedContent As String = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString()

    Debug.WriteLine(sSerializedContent)
    mem = ms
    xw.Close()

End Sub
```

Deserialize Method (where the problem lies)

```
Public Shared Function Deserialize(xmlStream As IO.MemoryStream) As Bitmap
    Dim serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Bitmap))
    xmlStream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    Return DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream), Bitmap)
End Function
```

Comment: [Use CDATA to store raw binary streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/502857/1115360) might give you ideas on how to do it.

Comment: You are serializing a JPEG. How do you expect this to be castable to a Bitmap object? You have to load the JPEG into a bitmap, e.g. with the appropriate constructor overload.