# Getting different byte array than written to file when reading from file

Tags: java, file, input, output, arrays

I'm writing my byte array to a file:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileOutput, true));
pw.write(new String(cryptogram, Charset.defaultCharset()));
pw.close();
```

Then, I am reading it from the file like this:

```
String cryptogramString = new String();
while (scPriv.hasNext()) {
    linePriv = scPriv.nextLine();
    cryptogramString += linePriv;
}
```

But I don't know how to make `byte[]` from `cryptogramString`. I'am trying this:

```
byte[] b = cryptogramString.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cryptogram));
```

But it doesn't return the same values. Does anyone have an idea how to make this right?

Comment: I don't understand _doesn't return me same values_. What are you comparing?

Comment: This doesn't actually sound like something that should be interacting with strings, but rather should be just using `InputStream` and `OutputStream` and dealing strictly with bytes?

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
is not the same as  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cryptogram));

Comment: I have a file that contains xml and then plain text, so i cant read a file as a whole

Comment: `hasNext` checks for an available token, while `nextLine` reads until the next line separator, excluding the line separator characters from the return value. Just read the file into a `byte[]` directly as previously suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decide whether you are writing text or binary.

Encrypted data is always binary which means you shouldn't be using Reader/Writer/String classes.

```
try (FileOutputstream out = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
    out.write(bytes);
}
```

to read back in

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) (new File(filename).length())];
try (FileInputstream in = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
    in.read(bytes);
}
```

> I have a file that contains xml and then plain text, so i cant read a file as a whole

You also can't write binary into a text file.  You can encode it using base64.

[Storing base64 data in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502814/storing-base64-data-in-xml)

Comment: I have file structure as follows

 `<xml>
       <tag>
       </tag>
</xml>
Cryptogram`
How could i read this Cryptogram with FileInputStream without reading xml? I cannot use base64 beacuse it extends the size.

Comment: You are mixing text (xml) and binary data in a single file? That is really not a good way to do it.

Comment: This are my requirements for this task and i have to do it this way. If it was up to me i would find different way.

Comment: @SzymonKaczorowski You can add it, but it won't be XML any more.

Comment: But how can i get this Cryptogram with FileInputStream?

Comment: @SzymonKaczorowski you have to read it the same as above, but you have to skip the XML first, but no more. I suggest reading it using the binary mode as well to avoid reading too much.